# HTTP Toolkit hit an error Server crashed with

Tags: http-toolkit

> 'Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:45456'
> (1). Please file an issue at github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit

what to do?

how to fix this error ?
i tried to uninstall and again install but my problem is not solve yet. How can I solve this problem and run that tool?

Answer (score 0):

This means that something else is running on your computer and using that port (45456). HTTP Toolkit needs to use that port, so this causes problems.

To fix this, you need to stop the other program from using that port. The most likely case is that HTTP Toolkit has failed to shut down correctly, and its internal proxy server is still running, which would cause this. That will appear in your system task manager as node.exe, and if you kill that process everything should work.

If that's not the cause there are many other ways to find out which program is using this port: [How do I find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows)

This shouldn't generally happen, so if you find that this occurs repeatedly or predictably then this is a bug, and you should report it at https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit so it can be fixed.